# Difference between index of List and index of Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I've encountered some rather bizzar exception while constructing connection string in my application.

```
string basis = "Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info={2};User ID={3};Password={4}";
List<string> info1 = new List<string>(){ "SQLSRV", "TEST", "True", "user1", "pass1" };
string[] info2 = new string[] { "SQLSRV", "TEST", "True", "user1", "pass1" };
// throws exception
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(basis, info1));
// works fine
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(basis, info2));
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

My question is: what is wrong with List's index?

Comment: Mention exception details please.

Comment: But why do you need to use `List<string>` on the first place ? You could use array initializer like `var info1 = { "SQLSRV", "TEST", "True", "user1", "pass1" };` and it'd work

Comment: The code could be simplified @Fabjan. Maybe that list is constructed somewhere else...

Comment: Yes it could, but if that's so OP should have mentioned it

Comment: Why, the question is legit as it is @Fabjan

Comment: The more details OP provide the better answer he would get. Let's say he uses this code as it is, and `List<string>` is *not* constructed outside of `Main`. If'd know that then the simplest answer would be to use string array.

Comment: @Fabjan The code is simplied, I'm just showing an example of this exception.

Comment: @maxMrScapegracerubanov Ok, in this case use of `.ToArray()` is sufficient

Comment: The title is somwhat confusing, it will misdirect future readers because of the `List(T).IndexOf` and `Array.IndexOf(T)` methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the index. In your first case you use this overload of `String.Format`:

```
public static void Format(string format, object arg);
```

and in the second you use this:

```
public static void Format(string format, params object[] args);
```

So in the first case you only pass **one** argument. That leads to an exception because your format string expects more than one argument.

In the second case you provide all arguments because an *array* instead of only one `List` object is passed.

Comment: Indeed, that is the best option in this case.

Comment: @maxMrScapegracerubanov yes that would be one possiblity. `info1.ToArray()` could work.

Answer (score 3):

It sees the list as a single parameter. The array is seen as the `params object[]  ...` parameter, giving multiple parameter values.

The problem is in the declaration of the `String.Format` method: The first takes `String Format(String format, object arg0)`, while the second takes `string Format(String format, params object[] args)`.

That makes the first one fail, since it expects more indexed than you supply.

Answer (score 3):

The Method `string.Format()` accepts an `object[]` as parameter to replace the placeholder of the format string.

`List` is not an Array so it is treated as a single object. Which therefore causes the exception because you are providing less parameters than placeholders in your format string.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx

> public static string Format(  string format,  params object[] args )

`String.Format` wants *array*: `params object[] args` as the second parameter, and when you provide a `List<String>` the *entire list* has been treated as the *1st item* of the array of objects and so the `Format` fails (you have to provide *five* items). The easiest remedy is, IMHO, obtain an array via Linq:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(basis, info1.ToArray()));
```